# sIFR3 - renders beautifully but links are not clickable

Tags: sifr

I've got sIFR3 running on my site but for some reason, links are not clickable. I've never experienced this issue before.. I'm only replacing h2 with it which is a linked title on my site. How do i enable sIFR to treat it as such?

Site is: http://criticaldesigner.com

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug in Firefox/Safari where a Flash movie with `wmode` set to `transparent` or `opaque`, contained in a floated element, doesn't properly register click events. Try removing the `wmode` setting if possible.